# Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'FormsModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angular

I'm new in Angular. I started Tour of Heroes to learn it.
So, I am created an `app.component` with `two-way` binding.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <h2>{{hero.name}}  details!</h2>
        <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
        <div><label>Name: </label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    hero: Hero = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Windstorm'
    };
}
```

Following the tutorial I imported FormsModule and added it into declarations array. Error appeared at this step:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      FormsModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is error:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'FormsModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: It's a "module". It belongs in `imports` and not `declarations`

Answer (score 277, accepted):

`FormsModule` should be added at `imports array` not `declarations array`.

- **imports array** is for importing modules such as `BrowserModule`, `FormsModule`, `HttpModule`
- **declarations array** is for your `Components`, `Pipes`, `Directives`

refer below change:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 9):

Add `FormsModule` in Imports Array.
i.e

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Or this can be done without using `[(ngModel)]` by using

```
<input [value]='hero.name' (input)='hero.name=$event.target.value' placeholder="name">
```

instead of

```
<input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="Name">
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the ***FormsModule*** from **Declaration:[]** and Add the ***FormsModule*** in **imports:[]**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: so, what did your answer add that the others didn't already provide ?

Answer (score 0):

**Things you can add to `declarations: [] in modules`**

- Pipe
- Directive
- Component

**Pro Tip**: The error message explains it - `Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.`